# Reference request: the ways of the world

Tags: reference-request, sutras, buddha

I am looking for sutta text where the Buddha says something like...

> The ways of the world will never be finished find your own salvation
>   with diligence...

Meaning, all the politics, hatered, war in this world will always continue you need not heed them and instead you should work towards your own salvation...

Comment: See also "[work out your salvation with diligence](https://fakebuddhaquotes.com/work-out-your-own-salvation-do-not-depend-on-others/)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "The affairs of the world will go on forever. Do not delay the
>   practice of meditation." - Milarepa

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [Pupphavagga](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ati/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.04.budd.html) or [Lokavagga](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ati/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.13.budd.html) or [Jesusvagga](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+16%3A33&version=GNT).

> *178. Better than sole sovereignty over the earth, better than going to heaven, better even than lordship over all the worlds is the
>   supramundane Fruition of Stream Entrance.*

Answer (score 1):

There are some (famous) lines in the [Maha-parinibbana Sutta (DN 16)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ati/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html)

> Therefore, Ananda, be islands unto yourselves, refuges unto yourselves, seeking no external refuge; with the Dhamma as your island, the Dhamma as your refuge, seeking no other refuge.

And

> Behold now, bhikkhus, I exhort you: All compounded things are subject to vanish. Strive with earnestness!

These don't quite match, "The ways of the world will never be finished"; but they are a good (maybe the best) match for, "find your own salvation with diligence".

There are various English translations, e.g. it's often translated "diligence" instead of "earnestness".